# Is the AWS ec2 private key specific to a user in the ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have an ec2 instance. I have a private putty key.
Currently I am logging in as root user.
So I created a new user, But unable to login directly as new user using this putty key.
Is this putty key specific to a instance user. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to add your public key to the user `authorized_keys` file in order to use your key with that user.

Your putty key does have a public portion that is stored on the server you want to access. If it works for the root user, its is in the `authorized_keys` file for the root user. Find the file here `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The file will be in `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` for all other users. If its not there you can create it, but pay attention to permissions.